# why event.target selects next element

Tags: jquery

I am having the following code. Here When i click one the `a` tag i just like to get `this element id` .but  `e.target` select next element can some one explain

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function doaction(e) {

       var eve, id;

        eve = $(e.target);
        id = eve.attr('id');
        alert(id);

    }

    $(".delete").click(function(e) {
        doaction(e);
    });


    });



<div class="delete" id="del/one"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="delete/1" >one</a></div>

<div class="delete" id="del/two"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="delete/2">two</a></div>

<div class="delete" id="del/three"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="delete/3" >three</a></div>
```

for demo

http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/SGvUd/4/

Comment: Your first `a` tag has two IDs, `delete/1` and `del/one`.

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsFiddle link works fine.  Just to explain, the click event is on the `div`, not on the `a`.  So, if you click on the `a`, you'll get that ID, but if you click inside the `div`, but not on the `a`, you'll get the `div` ID, not the `a` ID.  Since the `a` is inside the `div`, clicking on that will trigger the event.

Comment: i'm firing click event for div right... then how it give a tag id .. i need div id

Comment: @gowri: Use `$(this).attr('id')` inside the click handler to get the `div` ID.

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` gives you the actual element that was clicked.

To get the element that you registered the handler for, use `this`.

Comment: it doesn't give me div id thats my question why ?

Comment: @gow: Because you clicked on the `<a>`, not the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this: $(".delete").click(function(e) {

you're getting the click event of the DIV with a class nammed "delete"

if you whant to get the click of A tag you must put the class "delete" on tha a tag and make the following code Example:

$("a.delete").click(function(){ //Code here })

Comment: i want div id **id="del/one"** but it doesn't happen why

Comment: if you what the id you just have to do this:

var myID= $(e.target).attr("ID");

Answer (score 0):

It works ok for me. However, if you're having some problems, you may want to fix ID's in your code. The `ID` attribute's value must begin with a letter in the range A-Z or a-z and may be followed by letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function doaction(e) {

   var eve, id;

    eve = $(e.target.parentNode);
    id = eve.attr('id');
    alert(id );

}

$(".delete").click(function(e) {
    doaction(e);
});


});
```

e.target gives you actual element which is being clicked, and div is parent of that element so..use `e.target.parentNode` to get div id..

hope this helps..

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LqwxM/)